# Common Lisp output file streams SBCL

Tags: stream, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I am on SBCL on debian.

For some reason if I use this:

```
(with-open-file (output (open #p"file.txt"
               :direction :output
               :if-exists :overwrite))
   (format output "test")))
```

Where `file.txt` is a plain text file.

I get the error

```
#<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /home/me/file.txt" {1004A90813}> is not
a character output stream.
```

Even using `:element-type 'character` doesn't save me. I haven't been able to get any output stream opened by any method. If I try to use `write-bit` it says that it isn't a binary output stream. No other write functions work either, such as `write-sequence` or `write-line`. They all return this error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've made the important points bold. The problem is actually more tricky then one might think:

Let's look at the form.

First mistake: **it's not indented correctly**. Let's indent:

```
(with-open-file (output (open #p"file.txt"
                              :direction :output
                              :if-exists :overwrite))
  (format output "test")))
```

Now we can see more mistakes. **An additional parentheses**

```
(with-open-file (output (open #p"file.txt"
                              :direction :output
                              :if-exists :overwrite))
  (format output "test")))  ; <- additional parenthesis
```

But more important:

```
(open #p"file.txt"
      :direction :output
      :if-exists :overwrite)
```

Above opens a file for writing output and returns a stream.

`WITH-OPEN-FILE` does also open a file. **So you try to open the file TWICE, first for writing**..

```
(with-open-file (output stream)
  (format output "test")))
```

**Above opens a file for reading. You have opened the file twice: first for writing, then for reading.**

**Now you try to write with `FORMAT` to an input stream.**

The slightly surprising part is this: both `open` and `with-open-file` can take a file stream as a *file spec*. If it gets a file stream as a *file spec*, then the associated pathname is used for the *open* operation.

So, as mentioned in another answer, this would be more correct:

```
(with-open-file (output #p"file.txt"
                        :direction :output
                        :if-exists :supersede)
  (format output "Hello"))
```

**SBCL error message**:

```
#<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /home/me/file.txt" {1004A90813}>
is not a character output stream.
```

The point of the error message here is not that the stream is not a character stream. It's not an output stream. The stream actually is a character **input** stream! Thus calling `FORMAT` using the stream won't work. Let's write an assert to verify this:

```
CL-USER 18 > (with-open-file (output (open #p"/tmp/file.txt"
                                           :direction :output
                                           :if-does-not-exist :create
                                           :if-exists :overwrite))
               (assert (output-stream-p output) (output)
                       "The stream ~a is not an output stream!"
                       output)
               (format output "test"))
Error: The stream #<STREAM::LATIN-1-FILE-STREAM /tmp/file.txt>
is not an output stream!
```

**Your extra question**: Why is the following form working?

```
(with-open-file (input (open #p"file.txt")) ...)
```

It just opens the file TWICE for reading.

Comment: What a fantastic thoughtful answer thank you Rainer!

Answer (score 3):

Your usage of [`with-open-file`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_open.htm) is incorrect.

```
(with-open-file (output #p"file.txt"
                 :direction :output
                 :if-exists :supersede)
  (format output "Hello"))
```

Comment: That is interesting, because `(with-open-file (input (open #p"file.txt"))` was working without a problem.